# Prove the intersection of a Sylow $p$-subgroup and a subgroup is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

The statement we need to prove is:

Let $P$ be a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and let $H$ be any subgroup of $G$. Prove that $P\bigcap H$ is the unique Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Can you give some answers?
(Is $P\bigcap H$ normal in $H$?)

Comment: I have voted to close your question. Not because I think it is a bad question, but because you have shown no work or effort of your own.

Answer (score 3):

It is a general fact, easily proven directly from the definition via the conjugates, that if $N, H$ are subgroups of $G$, with $N$ normal in $G$, then $N \cap H$ is normal in $H$.

And then by Sylow's theorems all the $p$-Sylow subgroups of a given group, for a fixed prime, form a conjugacy class. So there is a unique $p$-Sylow subgroup if and only if such a Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal.