# If a group has one p-sylow subgroups, then this subgroup must be normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I've learned that this is true. Why, basically?
I'd appreciate you help.

Comment: It is good to remember that in general, if a group has one uniquely identifiable subset, then this subset must be fixed under all automorphisms of the group.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374920/prove-the-intersection-of-a-sylow-p-subgroup-and-a-subgroup-is-the-unique-sylo). Caranti's answer also gives the answer here.

Comment: @Myself That does seem good to remember, can you specify what "uniquely identifiable" means though?

Comment: It is worth noting that such a subgroup is characteristic, rather than simply normal, which means that it is fixed under all automorphisms of the original group, and not just those which are obtained by conjugation.

Comment: I have no precise definition. Uniquely identifiable means roughly, that if I give you a copy of a group, and a friend another copy, I can speak of a unique subset and trust that you and your friend will both find that subset, each in your own copy, without ambiguity. For instance, I could ask you to consider the set of all elements that commute with every other element; or the set of all elements that can be written as a product of commutators; or the set of all elements of order 2; or the set of all elements that can be written as a product of elements of order 2, etc.

Comment: @Myself Hehe, so I guess a good definition would be that it's fixed under all automorphisms.

Comment: @GPerez That would do it :-) But I think a logician could do something more with it, in the sense of a substructure that is well defined by a particular formula that makes no appeal to a direct 'construction' of the group.

Comment: @Myself Ah. Interesting indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H < G$ be the unique $p$-Sylow subgroup. Let $x \in G$. Then $xHx^{-1}$ is another $p$-Sylow subgroup, so $xHx^{-1} = H$ i.e. $xH=Hx$. This condition for all $x$ implies $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 2):

This is obvious.
Any subgroup which has unique order (the only group of such order) is normal.

The intresting in Sylow is the other direction. Namely, if $P$ is a normal subgroup of a group $G$ them it is unique.

This is because all the $p$-Sylow subgroups are conjugated.